# trying to check for a session if itexist and has value

Tags: coldfusion, lucee

i am writing a code to check for session and session value and if they do not exists or exists but have empty value or 0, i want them redirected

here is my start

```
<cfset lstofSessionsToCheck = 'EmplyID,Username'>

<cfset st = {}>
<cfloop collection="#session#" item="i">    
    <cfset SetVariable("st.session.#i#",duplicate(session[i]))>
</cfloop>
<cfparam name="redirection" default="false">
<cfif session.Username eq ''>
    <cfset redirection = true>
<cfelseif session.EmplyID eq ''>
    <cfset redirection = true>
</cfif>
```

it is missing some checks here

1. check if session is `defined` before it checks its value
2. if its defined, its value should not be `empty` or `0` or `-1`

please guide,m i am almost near its end but stuck at that

Answer (score 1):

[`session` is a special scope](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/the-cfml-programming-language/using-coldfusion-variables/about-scopes.html) in ColdFusion and either always or never exists. It depends on the state of [the `sessionManagement` attribute](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/developing-cfml-applications/using-persistent-data-and-locking/configuring-and-using-session-variables.html#Enablingsessionvariablesinyourapplication) in your `Application.cfc` (or `Application.cfm`/`<cfapplication>`). In case `sessionManagement` is `false`, accessing `session` will immediately throw an exception. I assume you are not seeing this error, so session management is enabled in your environment. That leaves you with checking if the session fields are initialized. Your new best friend is called [structKeyExists()](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-s/structkeyexists.html).

```
<!--- username needs to exist and must not be empty --->
<cfset hasUsername = (
    structKeyExists(session, "Username") and
    (len(session.Username) gt 0)
)>

<!--- ID needs to exist, must be a number and > 0 --->
<cfset hasID = (
    structKeyExists(session, "EmplyID") and
    isNumeric(session.EmplyID) and
    (session.EmplyID gt 0)
)>

<!--- if either username or ID is not properly set, do a redirect --->
<cfif (not hasUsername) or (not hasID)>
    <cfset redirection = true>
</cfif>
```

You can simplify the last line to a single expression:

```
<cfset redirection = ((not hasUsername) or (not hasID))>
```

As for your usage of [`setVariable()`](https://helpx.adobe.com/de/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-s/setvariable.html): You should generally avoid this function (along with [`evaluate()`](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-e-g/evaluate.html)) as they can be easily exploited and pose a security risk.

Rewrite:

```
<cfset st = {}>
<cfloop collection="#session#" item="i">
    <cfset SetVariable("st.session.#i#",duplicate(session[i]))>
</cfloop>
```

to

```
<cfset st         = {}>
<cfset st.session = {}>
<cfloop collection="#session#" item="i">
    <cfset st.session[i] = duplicate(session[i])>
</cfloop>
```

(And by the way, `i` is actually a key here, not a numeric index. Only use `i` with a for loop.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure the best way to do this is by looping through the entire thing every time you check. Unless those values are coming from a database or something after authentication?

Typically, if you want to restrict access to a page, you would check the `session` scope using `structKeyExists()`, for just a couple specific things.

The code would look something like this:

```
<!---This code sees if the user is logged in at all. If they are missing important information, I clear the session scope and redirect them to the login page. --->
<cfif !structKeyExists(SESSION, 'Username')>
    <cfset structClear(SESSION)>
    <cflocation url="YourPageHere" addtoken="maybe">
</cfif>

<!---This code checks for a specific permission to be defined. If not, it stops or redirects the user.--->
<cfif structKeyExists(SESSION, 'CanEditUsers') AND SESSION.CanEditUsers eq 1>
 <!---your code here--->
<cfelse>
 <cflocation url="YourPageHere" addtoken="maybe">
</cfif>
```

This is only a rough example - but hopefully puts you on the right path. Let me know if anything is unclear or needs to be edited to better fit your situation.